# Book/ Monograph on graph minor theory [Reference request]

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, graph-minor

I want to learn graph minor theory. Now i have read the very basic things and the overview from the book of R.Diestel but proceeding further is getting difficult. Currently, I am also following the [video lectures](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~jfgeelen/CO749/lectures.html) by Jim Geelan on graph minor theory.

Please suggest more books/monographs/lecture notes on graph minor theory. In case there is none, please suggest a systematic way to learn the concepts.

I posted the same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2399819/book-monograph-on-graph-minor-theory-reference-request), but not sure if it reached the right community.

Comment: It's not organized as a book, and not particularly comprehensive, but there's plenty of reading material in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Graph_minor_theory ...

Comment: Why not reading the 23 papers of Robertson and Seymour?

Comment: Perhaps, Descriptive Complexity, Canonisation, and Definable Graph Structure Theory by M. Grohe (https://lii.rwth-aachen.de/images/Mitarbeiter/pub/grohe/cap/all.pdf) is suitable as a start (cf. Chapter 17 there), since it is self contained?